# xCode 3.2.5: Developing non-fullscreen Camera to record stuff

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera

I am quite a beginner in iOS app development.
I am trying to develop an app to record a video with the iPad builtin rear camera.
I want the recording to not be a fullscreen, but takes only certain part of the screen, such as a half size of the screen, along with my own custom control displays.

How can I achieve this?

Please help

Comment: Side note - You really need to be using Xcode 4.6 if you want to learn iOS development. Using Xcode 3.2 means you are using a very old version that doesn't support iOS 6 or even iOS 5. And it won't support all of the new features of modern Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy. I realised this too, but as much as I want to upgrade the version, due to the limited development time of this project, I have to stick with xCode 3.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **AVFoundation** framework for this.

Have a look at this sample code
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks. This confirms and saves the development time